# Nested layout in react web component to show iphone preview screen stackoverflow

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, web-applications

How to create UI in React Web App which will show the preview of mobile app screen inside phone layout in order to show how it will look on for e.g. iPhone 8.

So my react web app has a component inside which preview frame layout should show some mobile's layout and dynamically change content such as text/image inside that preview window

Comment: Do you need this to check how your application will look on mobile? Or this is a requirement you need to implement in your application?

Comment: Just to check how it will look on a mobile screen
I have android studio UI screen in the app
I want to build preview framlayout in react webapp which will show mobile view